# Application Pallets move to main display when switching between applications in Mavericks

Tags: macos, display

I just recently upgraded to mavericks and I'm having an issue when using applications that have pallets.

For example, I'll use OmniGraph. I have my graph window on my main display and the Stencil pallet on my second display. When I switch to another application and then back to OmniGraph my stencil pallet will be on my main display covering my graph. On apps with many pallets this will be particularly annoying because they'll all be stacked on the main display.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on one of apple's support community posts:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6049450?searchText=mavericks%20pallet